# How to use between in stored proc in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to use `between` in a stored procedure. This is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_tb_sales_entry_total_product_where_date
   @to_date varchar(15),
   @from_date varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM tb_sales_entry_total_product 
    WHERE [Sales Date] BETWEEN @to_date AND @from_date
END
```

I passed two values `01-01-2014` and `10-01-2014`. In my table also in same format.

Problem is its not selecting values. Where is my error?

Comment: What type of field is [Sales Date]?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operator `BETWEEN` in SQL [has the following syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx):

```
test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

Since the `begin_expression` needs to be first, you have to switch the order of `from_date` and `to_date`:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_sales_entry_total_product WHERE [Sales Date] BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
```

Answer (score 4):

Switch them

```
WHERE [Sales Date] BETWEEN  @from_date AND @to_date
```

Answer (score -1):

use sql format..

DATE_FORMAT(colName,\'%d/%m/%Y\') AS colName

you can use the format you want.. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)